# React three fiber can we get AzimuthalAngle range from -infinity to +infinity instead of -pi to +pi, as we rotate around y axis

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I need helical movement of object i.e., as we rotate object forward object should move up and if we rotate backward object should move down, I am stuck since azimuthal angle ranges from -pi to pi.
here iam using getAzimuthalAngle() method

```
const Model = ({ controls }) => {
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (modelRef.current) {
      modelRef.current.position.y =
        controls.current.getAzimuthalAngle() / 1.6 - 0.8; //this moves object in y axis only from -pi to pi
    }
  });

  return (
    <group ref={modelRef}>
      <>
        <mesh position={[0.26, -3, 2.9]}>
          <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 0.00001]} position={[0, 0, 0]} />
          <MeshWobbleMaterial factor={0.2} speed={1} />
        </mesh>
      </>
    </group>
  );
};

const Scene = () => {
  const controls = useRef();

  if (controls.current) {
    const angle = controls.current.getAzimuthalAngle(); //this should be -infinity to infinity
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Model controls={controls} />

      <OrbitControls
        enableRotate={true}
        enableZoom={false}
        minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        ref={controls}
      />
      <ambientLight />
      <directionalLight />
    </>
  );
};
```